# Shimano Steps E600 trip meter

Tags: steps

Help please - I don't know how to enter settings on my *Shimano Steps E600* cycle computer or how to reset trip meter after journey.

Comment: Turns out there is no E600.  Do you mean E6000 ?

Answer (score 3):

1. The [manual](http://www.bike-manual.com/brands/trek/om/assets/pdfs/14shim_stepsuser.pdf)  says on page 24

[image]

2. THE SETTING MENU CANNOT BE LAUNCHED WHILE RIDING THE BICYCLE:  The product is designed in such a way that the settings menu cannot be launched if it detects that the bicycle is being ridden. This is not a sign of an abnormality.  Answer: Stop the bicycle to adjust the settings.

---

Resetting the trip meter is on page 27 of the manual.  Problem with this is its the bike's odometer, not a trip meter for each ride.  So by resetting this you have no idea how far your bike has gone in its life.  This is valuable information for servicing intervals.  It would be like clearing the odometer for a car.

[image]